# Stored procedures, functions and table types are not visible in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have created a new login which has only read rights. When I log into the new account, only tables are being displayed and stored procedures, functions and table types are not visible. I want all the tables, stored procedures, views, cursors, functions, table types to be visible but with only read and execute rights.

Can you please help me guys?

Answer (score 0):

How did you created your user? How did you granted rights? Most likely you missed something there. Here is how you can create a new login, create a user in your database for it, and give it read only rights:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE LOGIN [read_only_login] WITH PASSWORD=N'<enter_string_password_here>'
GO

USE [MyDatabase]
GO

CREATE USER [read_only_user] FOR LOGIN [read_only_login] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_datareader', N'read_only_user'
GO
```